# 'data:post-snippet' truncation in blogger

Tags: html, post, blogger, code-snippets, truncate

Let's say I wrote a post like this on Blogger:
abc def ghi <div class="pls-exclude-from-snippet">jkl mno pqr stu vwxyz</div>

Instead of listing from a to z, I want Blogger to set its data:post.snippet to 'abc def ghi' only (letting Blogger know to stop if it reads the token: a div with class 'pls-exclude-from-snippet'). How do I do that?

Comment: downvoting without stating why... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I found help here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/X9LxrjXnb2s

Still have to tweak it a little, but it works. Think gonna post it to help people with similar problem as I had.

Here's my code. Before `</head>`, add:

`<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function stopIfFound(strx,token){
      var theLocation = strx.indexOf(token);
      if(theLocation!=-1){
        strx = strx.substr(0,theLocation);
      }
      return strx;
    }
    function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop){
      strx = stopIfFound(strx,'<div class="pls-exclude-from-snippet">');
      if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1){
    var snippet = strx.split("<");
    for(var i=0;i<snippet.length;i++){
      if(snippet[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){
            snippet[i] =     snippet[i].substring(snippet[i].indexOf(">")+1,snippet[i].length);
          }
        }
        strx = snippet.join("");
      }
      chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;
      while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;
      strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);
      return strx+'...';
    }
    function createSnippet(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var summ = snippet_count;
    var summary = '<div class="snippets">' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) +  '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
    }
    //]]>
    </script>`

Find `<data:post.snippet/>`, in

```
 <div class='post-body'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.snippet'>
           <data:post.snippet/>
        </b:if>
      </div>
```

replace it with

```
<div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id'><data:post.body/></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>createSnippet(&quot;summary<data:post.id/>&quot;);  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to limit the length of the characters.

Use this syntax:

```
<b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 150})' />
```

**150** is the length. You can change it to any numbers you want.

Check my personal blog [change snippet length on Blogger without Javascript](https://www.igniel.com/2018/08/atur-jumlah-snippet-tanpa-script.html) to see more example.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It seems you are affiliated with the website in your answer. While we appreciate your answer, our policy requires that you disclose your affiliation. Would you mind adding that into your answer? Thanks

Comment: I have added it. Am i doing it right? Or i need to remove the link?

Comment: Yep. Good job for that. You can include links to your own websites in your answers if you include disclosure of affiliation. Cheers!